# Scheduling on Azure Notebooks

Tags: python, azure, cron, azure-notebooks

Is it possible to schedule a Python script on [Azure Notebooks](https://notebooks.azure.com/)?

I've written a simple script saved as `test.py`:
[image]

That runs absolutely fine when I run it in the terminal as

```
python library/code/test.py
```

I've got a cron that looks like this:
[image]

But nothing is produced when I save the cron. I've set it as `* * * * *` so there's no opportunity for confusion with timezones just whilst I'm testing.

I can't find where the cron might be emailing me errors and outputs within the Azure environment. My root directory looks like this and there's nothing in `mail`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to capture all the output. Here's a sample crontab entry set up to capture all the output:

```
59 13 05 06 * { /usr/bin/python /path/to/myscript.py -i /path/to/input.txt --log --timer ; } > /tmp/myProj/myscriptPY.trace.`/bin/date +\%Y\%m\%d.\%H\%M` 2>&1
```

Simple idea is to save jupyter notebook to local and write a shell script to submit the python script. Something like `/bin/bash -c "/path/to/python /path/to/script` ...". It could help,As it seems that cron uses /bin/sh to execute it's commands.

Try this and see if it helps.